# Взаимодействие с проектором через Ethernet

Tags: c++, http

Имеется проектор Panasonic PT-D4000U с Ethernet подключением. Необходимо написать приложение на C++ (Qt), которое по локальной сети заходит на страничку проектора, логинится и позволяет менять его настройки. С чего стоит начать и куда копать?

Comment: Разве Панасоник не предоставляет утилиты для настройки своих проекторов по сети?

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно некоторые команды интегрировать в оболочку Windows

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно разобраться в протоколе, который используется для взаимодействия Web Control Panel и проектора. В документации указано, что это PJLink.

Примеры кода на C++ для устройств поддерживающих протокол PJLink - [здесь](https://github.com/nullboundary/ofxPJControl)

Comment: Спасибо! Но я пока не смог понять, где найти список всех команд проектора по управлению выводом изображения, среди которых такие команды, как "ZOOM", "NORMAL", "WIDE"...